# Secure my internet web service for silverlight applications

Tags: silverlight, security, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight application that is out of browser and resides on the client desktop.  I want to make it call my web service that is on the internet.

How can I be sure that the call being made is valid and not an intruder?

In my head I want to say I can just pass a password that only the Silverlight application knows... but I am sure that will not work.

How do people typically do this sort of thing?

Comment: Security is very subjective, are you maintaining a list of high scores or does you site run a necular powerstation?  Its important to give some idea of the risks involved so that the level of effort needed can be assessed.   What you are asking for is not really possible unless you are willing to accept some moderate risk?  Are you sure you just don't need to authorise users instead?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on who you actually want to protect your web services from. I suppose that the issue here is that you don't want your user to use other applications to call your services.

A silverlight application runs on the clients computer. Everything that the silverlight application knows is also accessible for the end user or anyone else with access to that computer. That is, if silverlight can call your web service, then your end user may use other tools to make the same calls as well. You can create schemes that makes it difficult to do so, but it will be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use authentication SL + ASP .net membership provider:

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Leveraging-the-ASP.NET-Membership-in-Silverlight.aspx

Good luck
  Braulio

Comment: This would be standard user security but the question implies that its the application itself which is to be authorised not individual users.

Comment: If it's the app itself, I would just restrict the download (only authenticated user), then add a login at app startup. Once the app has been downloaded, it's on the client's machine so he can nicely dissasembly it or do whatever malicious he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i understand the question correctly so this answer might be bit off and sorry if it is.

Silverlight client call to wcf service is validated by clientaccesspolicy.xml.

In the **allow-from** section of that file you set from which hosting domain can silverlight application access the service, access from silverlight application hosted on different domain will result in crossdomain exception. But its probable that malicious user can change the hosting domain information in silverlight client.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <access-policy>
      <cross-domain-access>
        <policy>
          <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAP">
            <domain uri="http://my.domain.com"/> <!-- allowed domains -->
          </allow-from>
          <grant-to>
            <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
          </grant-to>
        </policy>
      </cross-domain-access>
    </access-policy>
```